# Java Android Room 'Attempt to recreate a file for type [Dao_Impl]'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am very much at a loss. I am simply trying to implement the Android Room tutorial found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). I keep receiving this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.example...dao.UserDao_Impl
```

Despite retrying the tutorial three times. If it helps:
My DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    // LiveData<> respects app lifecycle
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    LiveData<List<User>> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (:userIds)")
    List<User> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
            "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    User findByName(String first, String last);

    @Insert
    void insert(User planetEntity);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(User... users);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);
}
```

My database:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "climbing_app_database";
    private static AppRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public static AppRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (AppRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    //Creates the DB here
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AppRoomDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(new AppRoomDatabase.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                                    super.onCreate(db);

                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate anyone able to tell me how much of a sausage I am being.

I tried to repeat the tutorial 3 times, but I have to be skipping something on autopilot because I just want to curl into a ball

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your build.gradle (module-level) file, in my case (I was mixing Java & Kotlin) I had  both

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
```

and

```
ksp 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
```

Removing whichever I didn't need solved the problem for me. Refer to the accepted answer in this question
[Trying to create room database with android, but keep getting dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688349/trying-to-create-room-database-with-android-but-keep-getting-dependency-error)
for more information.